# Simple explanation for number of solutions of system of linear equations

Tags: linear-algebra

So a system of linear equations can be represented as:

$$Ax=d$$

where
$A$ is a $n\times n$ matrix and
$x$ and $d$ are $ n\times 1$ vectors.

Now in my notes it says the number of solutions are either:

$$0, 1 \text{ or } \infty$$

I understand if $\det(A) \neq 0$ then there is a unique one-to-one solution but could someone explain simply the other two cases in a easily understandable fashion?

Thank you.

Comment: BTW, this is true only for systems over infinite fields. In general, if a system has a solution then the number of solutions is the size of the field raised to the power of the number of free variables. In the case of an infinite field, this is infinity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement remains true even when $A$ is a matrix with different numbers of rows and columns.  Say that $A$ has $m$ rows and $n$ columns.  This corresponds to a system of $m$ equations in $n$ variables.

If $n=2$ then all of the equations represent lines.  If all $m$ lines cross in a single point, then there's a unique solution.   If all $m$ equations represent the same line, then every point on that line is a solution to the system, so there are infinitely many solutions.  If there is no point common to all $m$ lines, then there is no solution.

Could there be any other cases?  Could there, for example, be $2$ solutions?  If there were two equations, this would correspond to a pair of lines that intersect twice, but not infinitely many times, a clear impossibility.  In the case of $m$ lines, all $m$ of the lines would have to pass through the same $2$ points, but couldn't all be the same line.  Again, this is geometrically impossible.

If $n=3$, the equations represent planes.  It becomes harder to visualize all cases.  If all of the planes have a point in common, then there is a unique solution.  Two non-parallel planes will intersect in a line.  A third plane not parallel to that line will cross the line in a unique point—the unique solution.  One can think of many configurations where a set of planes have no point common to all planes—the no solution case.  There are essentially two ways to have infinitely many solutions: (1) have all of the equations represent the same plane, so that all points on that plane are solutions; (2) have all of the planes intersect in a common line, so that all points on that line are solutions.  In case (1), we have a $2$-parameter family of solutions; in case (2), we have a $1$-parameter family of solutions.  You can think about why, geometrically, it is impossible for a set of plane to have some other number of points in common.

Geometry, of course, only takes you so far.  The better way to understand why there are $0,$ $1,$ or infinitely many solutions is to understand row-reduction thoroughly.  If an inconsistency arises in the process of row-reduction, then there are no solutions; otherwise there are $1$ or infinitely many solutions.  Which one it is depends on whether there remain any undetermined parameters after row-reduction is complete.

Answer (score 1):

0:

For simplicity let's assume 2x2 matrix. Assume that after multiplication you get system of equations:

$x_1 + x_2 = 5$

$x_1 + x_2 = 10$

infinity:

Assume that after multiplication you get system of equations:

$x_1 + x_2 = 5$

$2x_1 + 2x_2 = 10$

---

To extend this on any $n$ x $n$ matrix:

- if the determinant of the non-homogeneous is zero, then

  - the system has infinite number of solution if it is not conflicted
  - the system has $0$ solutions if it is conflicted
- if the determinant of the non-homogeneous is different from zero, then the system has unique solution

Comment: I meant for a generic nxn case, I appreciate the example though

Comment: well, it is easy to extend this into general nxn case, the important is determinant is less than n and then might be 0 or infinite number of solutions

Comment: To expand on the last comment: If the rank is not equal to the dimension of the column space, or range space of $x\mapsto Ax$, then the image of $x\mapsto Ax$ does not fill the range space, and by the dimension formula, this linear function has a non-trivial kernel. So if $b$ is in the image of the function, the solution set is a translated copy of the kernel, with as many elements; and if $b$ is not in the image of the function, there is obviously no pre-image.

Comment: added general explanation